# Unable to scroll a UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to learn how to use UICollectionViewController. Using the code below, I am not able to scroll to the bottom row of cells.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ViewController *viewController = [[ ViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:[self flowLayout]];
    self.window = [[ UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[ UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *) flowLayout
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[ UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 20.0f;
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0f;
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake( 80.0f, 120.0f);
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake( 10.0f, 20.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f);
    return flowLayout;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
}
```

Additional Code from ViewController.m; The additional code was requested.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:( UICollectionView *) collectionView
  cellForItemAtIndexPath:( NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView 
            dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCollectionViewCellIdentifier 
                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [self allSectionColors][ indexPath.section];
    return cell;
}

- (NSArray *) allSectionColors
{
    static NSArray *allSectionColors = nil;
    if (allSectionColors == nil)
    {
        allSectionColors = @[ [UIColor redColor],
                            [UIColor greenColor],
                            [UIColor blueColor],
                            ];
    }
    return allSectionColors;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView :( UICollectionView *) collectionView
{
    return [self allSectionColors].count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without details on the model that is presented by the collectionView it's difficult to draw any conclusions regarding your problem. Two pointers are that first you're setting the scroll direction only to horizontal and second if the cell don't overflow the collectionView in any way then the latter will not be scrollable.

Comment: I have added what I guess is the model... the array of colors for the cells. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes! It looks like that you've got 3 sections each with a cell of different colour. If I'm not mistaken the cell's shouldn't take more than around 500 points vertically, so the last one should be inside the viewable area of the collection view. Hence scrolling is disabled by default. Change CGSizeMake( 80.0f, 120.0f) to CGSizeMake( 80.0f, 300.0f) and see if it scrolls then.

Comment: nstein: I am wondering if you meant 30.0f instead of 300.0f. When using 300.f there are only a few items in the first section that I am able to see, but with 30 all items are visible, though they are cut off so that each image is only partially seen.

Comment: With 300.0f can you scroll down to see the items that are only partially seen at first?

Comment: Have you got AutoLayout enabled? Try disabling it.

Comment: nstein: AutoLayout was disabled. Sorry for the delay in my response.

Comment: I've created a project based on your code and using a storyboard I added a collectionView with a prototype cell to which I gave an identifier. At first I couldn't actually see anything. As soon as I removed the code from applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: three small cells showed up and the collectionView was scrollable. Try using a storyboard if you're not doing so already. By the way if you're doing so there is no apparent reason for using the custom initWithCollectionViewLayout. Just add the layout method in the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can't scroll to the bottom row of cells because you set the scroll direction to horizontal:

```
flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
```

Use `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical` instead.

Comment: Horizontal instead of Vertical was a typo, and I still cannot scroll though all of the cells which are arranged in vertical columns.